# Passing variables to jquery function

Tags: jquery, variables

I'm trying to pass a changing variable to jquery function below but missing a piece.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){    

  var area = "NW";

  $("#NWbutton").click(function (){
   $('#mainmap > img').attr('src', "some_web_"+area+"_address_forpics_time.gif");
  });


});
```

For the "NWbutton" I need var area = "NW".  I have 20 or so buttons with corresponding variables.  How do I pass these for each button instead of writing out each variable?

Comment: You could use an array for your area, and loop on them.

Comment: how are you using selector, I think there should be either `#NWbutton` or `.NWbutton` or `button`? what is just `NWbutton`?

Comment: Yes it should read ("#NWbutton")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` attributes provide the perfect solution to this problem. You can put whatever data is related to that button into the attribute, which you can then read in the `click` handler. Something like this:

```
<div id="mainmap">
    <img src="foo.jpg" data-area="NW" />
    <img src="bar.png" data-area="SW" />
</div>
```

```js
$("#NWbutton").click(function (){
    $('#mainmap > img').attr('src', function() {
        return "some_web_" + $(this).data('area') + "_address_forpics_time.gif";
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Following Rory McCrossan , individual `button`'s or `input[type=button]`'s could include`text` or `value` corresponding to selection variable for that element, i.e.g.,

`<button>NW</button>`

or

`<input type="button" value="NW" />`

html

```
<div id="mainmap">
    <img src="foo.jpg" alt="NW"/>
    <img src="bar.png" alt="SW"/>
    <img src="baz.jpg" alt="NE"/>
    <img src="foobar.png" alt="SE"/>
</div>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
  // with `input` elements , substitute
  // `input[type='button']` , `$(e.target).val()`
  // for `button` , `$(e.target).text()` , respectively
  $("button").click(function (e) {
   var area = $(e.target).text();
   $('#mainmap > img[alt='+ area +']')
   .attr('src', "some_web_" 
         + area
         + "_address_forpics_time.gif");
  // console.log($("img[alt='" + area + "']").attr("src"))
  });    
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/hphe11qu/